# Middleware doesn't protect routes based on role

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, middleware, roles

I made a similar question hours ago but it haven't recieved much answers so that is the reason I'm asking the same but I will try to maybe word it diferently to maybe make it more clear, I only got one answer in that question but it didn't worked. I'm going to put a link to my previous question if you want to see it.

[Can't protect Routes based on role Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69225968/cant-protect-routes-based-on-role-laravel-8)

The problem I have is that I'm trying to use a middleware to allow access to some routes only if they have the respective role.

The code of my middleware is this (the one suggested in the answer provided on my previous question).

```php
         <?php
            
            namespace App\Http\Middleware;
            
            use Closure;
            use Illuminate\Http\Request;
            
            class EnsureUserHasRole
            {
                /**
                 * Handle an incoming request.
                 *
                 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
                 * @param  \Closure  $next
                 * @return mixed
                 */
                public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $role)
                {
            
                    if (! $request->user()->role($role)->get()) {
                        // Redirect...
                       
                        return back();
                    }
                        
                    return $next($request);
            
            
                }
            }
```

The code of my User model is this

```php
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    
        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        
        protected $fillable = [
            'role',
            'name',
            'email',
            'password',
            'idPersona',
            'estado'
        ];
        
        public function Persona(){
            return $this->belongsTo(Persona::class,'idPersona');
        }
        /**
         * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = [
            'remember_token'
        ];
    
        /**
         * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $casts = [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        ];
    
        public function scopeRole($query, $role)
        {
            return $query->where('role', $role);
        }
    }
```

Not sure if it can help but my User table in my database its like this

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idPersona` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 31,
  `prueba` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `users_FK` (`idPersona`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`idPersona`) REFERENCES `personas` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

I'm testing my middleware with this Route, in this case I'm trying to let only the `administrador` to access the route and if not then just return. (the middleware role is the one in the code above).

```
  Route::get('/gestionarMedicos', [PersonaController::class,'mostrarMedicos'])->name('personaMostrarMedicos')->middleware('auth','firstLogin','role:administrador');
```

The problem is all users can access it. I think its a logic issue because if I display what the if returns with a dd() outside the if it displays `false`, even in the `administrador` role.

Comment: What is the `$a` variable? `$a=! $request->user()->role($role)->get()`. What's the output of `dd($role);` in your middleware?

Comment: the $a variable was for testing with a dd() what the if returned, in this case it always returns false. If I do dd($role) in the middleware it returns administrador idependent of the role that the user logged in has.

Comment: Just to avoid misleading information, can you remove the `$a` variable, test again and update your question once it's done? Everyone will only see this. I'm only seeing this, both as an error (PHP will throw a notice) and as a potential cause of your issue (which is probably wrong, but deleting will remove any doubt).

Comment: already edited the answer, why was the question downvoted? I don't see anything wrong with it to deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your middleware method to this:

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    // dd($request->user()->role, $role); 
    // uncomment this for testing purpose if it's not working, both should be equal to "administrator"

    if (!$request->user() || $request->user()->role != $role) {
        // Redirect...
                       
        return back();
    }
                        
    return $next($request);           
}
```

What you previsously had, `$request->user()->role($role)->get()`, will return a Collection of administrators.

It's not what you are looking for. You just want to check if the current user, `$request->user()`, is an administrator.

Since a user has a `role` column, just checking if the `$role` you provided is the same should be enough.

In english, the if statement says "if there is no user or if the user has a column `role` with a value not equal as `$role`, then redirect back".

---

#### What if you need multiple roles?

Use a variadic function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list).

Add the `...` in function declaration (`...$roles`) :

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
{
    //dd($roles); 
    //is now an array with all the roles you provided to the route.

    if (!$request->user() || !in_array($request->user()->role, $roles)) {
        // Redirect...
                       
        return back();
    }
                        
    return $next($request);           
}
```

Using a variadic function allows you to convert a string argument to an array.

In your route, you can now add multiple roles:

```
  Route::get('/gestionarMedicos', [PersonaController::class,'mostrarMedicos'])->name('personaMostrarMedicos')->middleware('auth','firstLogin','role:administrador,client,somethingelse');
```

In the middleware, `$roles` will be equal to:

```php
['administrador', 'client', 'somethingelse']
```

Comment: I did it, first one shows cliente and second one shows administrador

Comment: Can you confirm it enters the if statement?

Comment: It works now, also as a bonus question. What happens if a Route should be available for multiple roles, I have 3 roles and some routes can be accessed by 2 of the 3 roles.

Comment: Glad it works! I'll update my answer to answer the bonus.

Comment: also just wondering why the first condition !$request->user() has the ! than in english means does not if I'm not mistaken. Shouldn't the first condition check if the request cotains the user instead of having the !

Comment: I updated my answer. Yes the `!$request->user()` is just a security to ensure if there is no user logged in (guest), then your middleware should act as the role wasn't allowed. It will prevent you from errors in case there is no user (`Trying to get property of non object...`)

Comment: I get it now, its to check if an unlogged person is trying to access the route in that case. I think auth middleware does that but its never bad to be careful. Also why second condition for multiple roles doesnt have the ! that the single role function has?

Comment: Yes you are right. It's just in case you are using the role middleware without the auth middleware, since we cannot be 100% sure it will never happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237232/discussion-between-diego-utreras-and-toyi).